# What's the difference between [short-story] and [short-fiction]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've stumbled upon the tag [short-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-fiction), which sadly has neither a tag wiki excerpt nor a full tag wiki. Looking through the questions tagged with [short-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-fiction) I can see that most of them (10 of 18) have the tags [short-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-fiction) and [short-story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story).

What is the difference between the two?

It looks to me like we could just get rid of [short-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-fiction) and replace it where necessary with [short-story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story) and [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction), as it seems to be a mixture of the genre tag [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction) and the format tag [short-story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story). I couldn't find anything explicitly about short-fiction with a quick search that lead me to the Wikipedia article about short-stories or articles discussing whether all short-stories are automatically fiction.

Are there any subtle differences I am missing? If so, could someone update the tag wiki so that the difference can be found more easily and check whether the questions are tagged correctly?

Comment: I agree; that sounds redundant. See also [tag:flash-fiction], which *is* a separate thing (and has its own tag already).

Comment: Agreed, we should consolidate or at least make one of these a tag synonym. I'd suggest keeping short-fiction around, since it includes novellas and the like.

Comment: @NeilFein We already have a tag for [tag:novella]s.

Comment: I have deleted the tag [short-fiction] from all questions that explicitly ask about a specific type of short fiction (such as short story or novella) and not short fiction in general as well as from questions where the type of story is irrelevant to the question, such as questions about writing exercises. I have left the tag [short-fiction] in all questions that ask about fiction of less than novel-length in general (e.g. how to sell short fiction). There are now six questions left tagged [short-fiction]. This will make it easier to decide what should happen with those questions and that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Cloudchaser's [edit](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/whats-the-difference-between-short-story-and-short-fiction#comment3904_1539) (thank you!), five questions remained with the [short-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-fiction) tag.  I reviewed all of them, and all of them were about a more specific type of short fiction (usually short stories).  [This one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/21032/1993) about making money from short fiction was the most ambiguous; it refers to publishing in magazines in the past, which could mean short stories or novellas.  I retagged it [short-story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story) anyway; there were already five tags so I didn't try to add [novella](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novella).

Answer (score 2):

There are many other types of short fiction that aren't short stories:

- [novella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novella)
- [anecdote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdote)
- [fairy tale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_tale)
- [legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend)
- [calendar stories](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalendergeschichte) (German link)
- [ballad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballad)
- [radio drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_drama)
- [parable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable)
- [joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke)
- [comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comics)
- [reviews of nonexistent books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem's_fictitious_criticism_of_nonexisting_books)
- [flash fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_fiction)

and those are only the ones that come to mind quickly.

---

The tag [short-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-fiction) makes sense for questions that are about specific types of non-short-story short fiction, such as [One-page tales: what do I have to spit out and what is indispensable?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/23403/one-page-tales-what-do-i-have-to-spit-out-and-what-is-indispensable), and for questions that ask about fiction of less than novel length in general and aren't limited to a certain type of short fiction, such as [Can I make money from short fiction?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/21032/can-i-make-money-from-short-fiction)

I have edited the tag descriptions accordingly. Please improve.